# Difference between "у тебя всё хорошо" and "ты в порядке"

Tags: лексикон, разница, словарь

What is the difference between **"у тебя всё хорошо?"** and **"ты в порядке?"**?

Comment: Do you mean the question forms? **"У тебя всё хорошо?"** vs. **"Ты в порядке?"**

Comment: @IvanOlshansky Yes

Comment: This is actually to ask something like what is the difference between "Is everything alright?" and "Are you OK?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is little semantic difference:

1)  "у тебя всё хорошо?" - is more about "outer" circumstances (like bank loans, home and work life)

2)  "ты в порядке?" - is more about person himself (like health and well-being)

It's not a strict rule. This questions are quite interchangeable.

Comment: I would use "ты в порядке?" if someone has taken a fall, or if there's been a terrorist attack and I want to know they're all-right - all kinds of immediate circumstances. If I were asking about a person's general health, I'd still use "у тебя всё хорошо?"

Comment: You are right in general, but you still can use both variants for both situation. And after terorists attack both questions can be asked in one phrase (my personal expireens of living in Moskow)

Answer (score 1):

The *difference* is that the *latter* expression is *not Russian* in origin and actually comes from amateur translations; it literally renders the English *'Are you alright/OK?'* Typical Russian expression of that sense is: **У тебя всё в порядке (хорошо)?** The version *Ты в порядке?* while often used (definitely not by everybody) in the recent years, doesn't sound too sophisticated to me. If you google that expression in books, unlikely you'll find it in *classical* literature (most results come from books written in 2017-2019).

Comment: I searched «ты в порядке» and «я в порядке» at Ruscorpora. Earliest mention is in «Некуда» by N. S. Leskov (1864).

Comment: @Neith The only Ruscorpora's hit from the past ("я в порядке" from Leskov) is neither a question nor an example of the same sense: its usage is based on literal meaning. In that context, it's about a lady's appearance being in order (the character means she's almost ready to meet her guests and asks just to apply a pin: - А мужчины? - прошептала Женни. - Что ж, я в порядке. Зашпиль мне кофту, и пусть придут.) and by no means about being safe or having no problems (as in modern colloquial usage instead of "у тебя всё хорошо?"). The other results - mainly from 2000s (Dontsova/Marinina/Ustinova).

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the most upvoted answer by ksbes is not complete.
1) is more general
2) is more time constrained to the immediate present and feels like a borrowed from English 'are you all right' father than a native idiom. Alex_ander provided a more native version of it.